# Do I need Past perfect tense when the order of verbs is from first to last?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect

I am learning about the past perfect tense and I'm beginning to think that the tense is never really required for the sentence to be grammatical.  It is mainly a tense to help clarify the order of the verbs.  So, if the order of verbs follows the usual chronological order, do I ever *need* to use the past perfect for the sentence to be grammatical?

Comment: There is a very detailed answer to your question [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-is-the-past-perfect-exactly-needed).

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me.  For example if I changed the tense of the following sentence from past perfect to present: "I had gone the night before." to "I  go the night before." It's still grammatical but means something entirely different.  But, "I had finished eating when the package arrived." changing to present tense: "I finish eating when the package arrived." is not grammatical.  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @Jim I was asking about when I _needed_ to use the past perfect over the past tense for it to be grammatical and keep its meaning.

Comment: Ok, then yes, sometimes past perfect is necessary: "I had finished eating when the package arrived." becomes "I finished eating when the package arrived." is still grammatical but has a different meaning.

Comment: @Jim what about "I already finished eating, when the package arrived"? thanks

Comment: To me that feels like the past perfect with the *had* elided rather than simple past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you do; sometimes you don't.

Sometimes, you want to clearly portray something as preexisting, so you do use pluperfect:

> I had met her dozens of times, but this time was the first time I
>   really saw her.

Other times, you are simply relaying a series of events, so you don't use pluperfect:

> My grandma didn't give me a cookie, so I punched her in the nose.

You are looking for a hard-and-fast rule, but as is true of every rule of grammar, there are exceptions, and even exceptions often have exceptions.